# cx_Freeze: Python error in main script

Tags: python, django, executable, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I am a beginner in python and django. This error keeps coming, even after installing cx_freeze from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze
I am trying to make an executable file and I want to run my server through it, which I normally do by:

```
manage.py runserver
```

I am currently using commands:

```
setup.py build
```

I have already tried:

```
pyinstaller --name=mysite myproject_dir/manage.py
```

and my setup.py file contains

```
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
       name = "Management System",
       version = "1.0",
       description = "A Database Management System",
       py_modules=['virtualenv'],
       executables = [Executable("manage.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

I have also tried py2exe, it doesn't work. You can also suggest to read something for this knowledge.

[Here is the image of error that keeps appearing on running the exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHmiy.jpg)

If I use this command:
    Barcode.exe runserver
There also comes an error

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:'C:\\Users\\D ell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI85~1\\Entry\\migrations/*.*'
```

Comment: For what purpose do you need the executable?

Comment: Have you tried [doing this](https://algotronics.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/dj2exe/)

Comment: Also, PyInstaller has a [dedicated page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django) on making Django executables, which includes a section on what to do when there are `import` errors like the one you have.